# Is it better to store integers instead of full text?

Tags: elasticsearch, normalization, data-modeling, database-normalization

I'm trying to put together a reporting solution using ES.
As my experience with ES is rather basic, I would like to know if it makes a difference if I'm using integers when filtering.

I know what the values of my filters will be and that I will not be allowing for full text search.

Therefore in my query I can either have

```
{
  "filter" : {
    "term" : { "gender" : 1 }
}
```

or

```
{
  "filter" : {
    "term" : { "gender" : "male" }
}
```

Would it be quicker to use the integer instead of the string search?

Also, I assume that using the integer it'd be better for disk space, right?

Finally, am I just better off using MySQL in such a case - where no full text search is not required?

Many thanks in advance,
Angel

Answer (score 1):

For filters it's not likely to make a difference. Something to keep in mind, however, is that during an aggregation, doc-valued string fields (eg non analyzed ones) are going to be loaded into an on-heap memory map called global ordinals. Depending on the number of possible values (which for gender will presumably be very small) that can exert a great deal of pressure on the JVM.

You might try mapping this as a boolean field, potentially. You'd save a bit of space if you did that, or if you mapped it as a integer. But from a querying perspective, it should make any difference.

As far as MySQL vs ES, that's a trickier and much more nuanced question. It depends on (among other things) what you are trying to do, how much data you're working with, and whether or not you require transactional guarantees and/or MVCC. Both MySQL and ES will perform quite well with a filter like this (assuming you put a secondary index on gender in MySQL... which in effect would be a B-Tree based version of the relationship mapped by Lucene). Based on the info you've provided, there isn't really a good reason to prefer one tool over another. You'd either need to provide more context or (perhaps even better) give it a shot in both and see which one you're happier with.

Best of luck.

Comment: Wow thanks for this! I assume at the end of 2nd paragraph you mean "it shouldn't make any difference"?

Basically the whole reporting module I'm working on it fetching tons of log entries from a "data lake", process and prepare them for filtering.

The idea was to have the processed nginx / squid / etc logs saved into their respective tables in MySQL, but we shifted into a denormalised ES sort of context where a document of "user" type would have the user attributes and then arrays of nested objects for nginx logs, squid logs, etc per minute.

Does this make sense?

Comment: "I assume at the end of 2nd paragraph you mean "it shouldn't make any difference"  -- you are correct, yes.

Comment: I would lean towards ES instead of MySQL on this. Logging data typically don't require durability and serializibaility guarantees and, if you needed to search your logs, it's gonna be a lot easier to do that in ES. Also, I assume you'd want to expire the logs after a certain amount of time. In ES, this is very easy to manage. In MySQL, deleting data from a table does not reclaim the disk space. So you'd need to run optimize table periodically to trigger a compaction, which will lock your table for writes while it runs. Unless you require the guarantees MySQL gives you, I'd probably use ES